# FIX NewOrderSingle recieves Internal application error, contact support

Tags: c++, quickfix, fix-protocol

Im developing a bot in c++ using QuickFix, using Remarkets to test my app but when I send a newOrderSingle y get **"Internal application error, contact support."**

I assume the application is myself, but i also tried to contact Remarkets without any answer.

**The messages go like this:**

Logon:

```
8=FIXT.1.1 9=124 35=A 34=1 49=usr123 52=20201012-21:00:35.860 56=ROFX 553=usr123 554=hdjbxA7# 98=0 108=30 141=Y 1137=9 10=129
```

Logon answer:

```
8=FIXT.1.1 9=89 35=A 34=1 49=ROFX 52=20201012-21:00:36.534 56=usr123 98=0 108=30 141=Y 1137=9 10=246
```

Recieve this Trading Session Status that i dont fully understand:

```
8=FIXT.1.1 9=114 35=h 34=2 49=ROFX 52=20201012-21:00:38.069 56=usr123 325=Y 335=NONE 336=[N/A] 340=2 1300=DDF 1301=ROFX 10=098 
8=FIXT.1.1 9=115 35=h 34=3 49=ROFX 52=20201012-21:00:38.069 56=usr123 325=Y 335=NONE 336=[N/A] 340=2 1300=DUAL 1301=ROFX 10=188 
8=FIXT.1.1 9=114 35=h 34=4 49=ROFX 52=20201012-21:00:38.069 56=usr123 325=Y 335=NONE 336=[N/A] 340=2 1300=DDA 1301=ROFX 10=095 
8=FIXT.1.1 9=115 35=h 34=5 49=ROFX 52=20201012-21:00:38.069 56=usr123 325=Y 335=NONE 336=[N/A] 340=2 1300=MERV 1301=ROFX 10=210 
8=FIXT.1.1 9=115 35=h 34=6 49=ROFX 52=20201012-21:00:38.069 56=usr123 325=Y 335=NONE 336=[N/A] 340=2 1300=RFXI 1301=ROFX 10=210 
8=FIXT.1.1 9=128 35=h 34=7 49=ROFX 52=20201012-21:00:38.070 56=usr123 58=EXTERNAL 325=Y 335=NONE 336=[N/A] 340=2 1300=MATBA 1301=ROFX 10=009 
8=FIXT.1.1 9=118 35=h 34=8 49=ROFX 52=20201012-21:00:38.581 56=usr123 325=Y 335=NONE 336=1 340=0 625=1 1300=[N/A] 1301=ROFX 10=216
```

**I try to buy**

```
8=FIXT.1.1 9=151 35=D 34=2 49=usr123 52=20201012-21:00:39.084 56=ROFX 1128=7 11=1132322 21=1 40=1 44=250 54=1 55=SOJ.ROSNov20 59=0 60=20201012-21:00:39 99=1 10=151
```

**Get this rejection**

```
8=FIXT.1.1 9=145 35=j 34=9 49=ROFX 52=20201012-21:00:39.225 56=usr123 58=Internal application error, contact support.13558951763361350 372=[N/A] 380=4 10=036
```

I have tried several ways to make this message, always getting the same response.

My questions:

- Is there something wrong with my newOrderSingle?
- I have a working bot in python using pyRofex. Is there a way for me to see what fix message is pyRofex generating?
- Is it OK to use tag 55 for the instrument?  `55=SOJ.ROSNov20`  I've seen some examples with value "EUR/USD" in that field. Should the symbol be a part of a group?
- About ClOrdID: Remarkets documentation states that

> Orders  should  have  a  unique  identifier  (tag  ClOrdID  <11>)  assigned  by  the  institution  for  a  trading  day.  Orders  with duplicate identifiers will be rejected by the exchange.

But every client y see is managing those ClOrdIDs internally. I understand that the only constrain is that it does not repeat in a single market day. Did i get it right?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `380=4`, if they're using codes correctly, suggests the application's not available. To rule out something being caused by your order, try sending something else, like a heartbeat, gap fill, or resend request.

Comment: Hi! I am sending and receiving hartbeats successfully, also I get a Logon answer. I think they are online. What other thing could be "not available"?

Comment: Suppose though after the logon success, you send an order and the "exchange" is not ready to handle this order or something is invalid about your request, then perhaps the "exchange" goes into a bad state and is no longer available. Not sure though sorry, sounds very specific to that application.

Comment: Why don't you ask the counterparty?

Comment: Hi! Cristoph, ask like in a fix message? If you mean contacting the people who make the acceptor I've tried vía mail and phone, no answer. Maybe we don't need to solve this completely but with some help on the questions I could figure this out. Thank you both!

Comment: Hmm you are sending a market order with tags 99/StopPrice and 44/Price? Looks odd to me.

Comment: Remarkets is not aswering requests right now, I don't know why. Buy as soon as I can I will edit the post with all the messages that I've tried, always getting the same response. I've tried without tag 99.

Comment: Also without 44? No need on market order.

Comment: Tag 373 should help but the tag itself missing in your reject message.

Comment: Thanks, its solved. The problem was that I was trying with 40=1 (Ordertype = market) and i needed 40=2 (Ordertype = limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it right! I have yet to understand the deatils, when I become an expert in fix protocol y promisse I will come and explain, but for the moment i can give you the message that allowed me to buy Option futures.

```
8=FIXT.1.1                //Dictionary
9=220                     //Body Length
35=D                      //Message type. D= New order single
34=2                      //MdgSeqNum 
49=myuser                 //User
52=20201016-00:21:56.758  //Sending time
56=ROFX                   //Target comp ID
1128=7                    //Dictionary version? 7=FIX50SP2
1=REMXXXX                 //Account
11=1223221                //ClOrdID 
21=3                      //HandlInst. 3=manual order
22=8                      //ID source. 8=Exchange Symbol
38=2                      //Number of shares ordered. 
40=2                      //Order type. 2=LIMIT   *1
44=100                    //Price
54=1                      //Side. 1=BUY 2=SELL
55=SOJ.ROSNov20 220c      //Symbol
60=20201016-00:21:56      //Time of execution/order creation        
167=OPT                   //Security type. OPT=options
200=NOV20                 //MaturityMonthYear 
202=100                   //StrikePrice 
231=100                   //ContractMultiplier
461=F                     //CFI_CODE. F=FUTURE      
10=118                    //CheckSum


*1: I dont yet understand the difference between order "LIMIT" or "MARKET" but that is what solved it.
```

With that message I got this answer:

```
8=FIXT.1.1|9=315|35=8|34=9|49=ROFX|52=20201016-00:21:56.900|56=user|1=Account|6=100.0000|11=1223221|14=2|17=T7661551|31=100.0|32=2|37=189923278|38=2|39=2|40=2|44=100.0|54=1|55=SOJ.ROSNov20 220c|58=Operada |59=0|60=20201016-00:21:56.898|150=F|151=0|207=ROFX|382=1|375=PMYVTR|453=1|448=user|447=D|452=11|10=174|
```

About my question involving ClOrdID<11>: It's managed from the client, the only limitation is not to repeat the same ID in a single trading day.

To sell a future option, the same message changing Side<54> from 1(BUY) to 2(SELL) works just fine.

I'm pretty sure that i have extra fields in my message, will ckeck that.

Thank you all for your answers, they helped a lot!

Comment: Limit orders have a price given by the one who enters them, market orders are sold/bought at market price and hence do not contain a price.